# Mapping URL path parameters with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to map the path parameter form part of the request URL:

[example](http://host.net/people/:123456-7)

I am doing this but it doesn't work:

```
@app.route("/people/:<string:id>", methods=['GET'])
def api_search_a_person(id):
   return Id
```

Does anyone know how to get the value after the ":" (string "123456-7" in the example)

Answer (score 0):

`:` is a special URI character because it's used to define the protocol or port, so it's likely that your browser [URI encodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the character.

Do you really need this character anyway ? Can't you simply remove it (`http://host.net/people/123456-7`), or use URI parameters instead `http://host.net/people/?123456-7` ?

If you really want to use a `:`, escape it on both ends (the escape character is `%3A`).

Comment: I've tried with `:` before `<string_id>` and it has no issues on my machine, `http://..../:123456-7` gives me `123456-7` desired response in my example code. I think the problem was the `:` within the `<string:id>` and also the return of `Id` which appears nowhere... Effectively, he mapped the catching of the `string_id` wrong IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@app.route("/people/:<string_id>", methods=['GET'])  # notice _ instead : 
def api_search_a_person(string_id):  # extracts the string_id from the request url
    return string_id  # returns the mapped string_id
```

It's unclear why you used `<string:id>` with `:` inside.

And also what `Id` represents in the return (maybe you meant `id` from the method parameter ...